# python3 / Gtk3 application freezing on Windows 8

Tags: windows, multithreading, python-3.x, freeze, gtk3

I'm a hobbyist programmer and have written a small application using Python3 and Gtk3.

It has **two threads** in it. One is a simple clock showing current time and updating the GUI every minute. The other is a countdown timer which can be started and stopped (the thread is killed with a flag on pause, and a new thread created on start). Both threads are **daemons** and **neither interacts with the other**.

It is working perfectly in linux.

In Windows it freezes / locks up, even when I haven't started the timer (i.e. only the clock thread is active). Windoze complains: "**Python.exe is not responding**".

My initial question is just whether it is safe to use threads in Windows. Or perhaps it is not a good idea to use GTK3?

Has anyone else experienced something like this?